# Is there a away to convert IList<ArraySegment<byte>> to byte[] without enumerating through the List and adding to a new byte[]?

Tags: c#, arrays

I understand I could enumerate through the IList such as:

```
public byte[] ConvertToByteArray(IList<ArraySegment<byte>> list) {
    IList<byte> newList = new List<byte>();
    foreach(var asb in list) {
       for ( int i = asb.Offset; i < (asb.Offset + asb .Count); i++ )  {
           newList.Add(asb.Array[i]);
       }
    }
    return newList.ToArray();
}
```

but that seems rather ugly, is there a nicer way of doing this?

Comment: list.SelectMany(x => x.Array).ToArray();

Comment: You know that ArraySegments can be overlapping? Is this what you want?

Comment: @Phill That could result not only in you getting multiple copies of the same array, but *best-case* getting elements that aren't included in `list`, and possibly getting all of those extra elements many times.

Comment: As a suggestion, unless you can pre-size the array (or the list), you should try to return an IEnumerable<byte>. Let the CALLER call the ToArray. So you should implement your ConvertToByteArray to an iterator that returns IEnumerable<byte>. In your small example, you are copying the same data twice (once in the newList, the second time in the Array). In the end perhaps the caller will simply foreach your result, and you'll have done two copies for nothing, when a simple IEnumerable would have been enough.

Comment: @Matt - How so? SelectMany just flatterns the array, and ToArray just returns it to an array instead of a IEnumerable<T>... I'm not sure how SelectMany would result in multiple copies of the same array or having extra elements returned... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx "Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable<T> and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence."

Comment: @Phill because the Array property on an ArraySegment does not return the contents of the segment as an array, but a reference to the underlying array over which the segment is presenting a view of. You can have multiple ArraySegments, all distinct, constructed on the same array, and for each of them, `segment.Array` would return the same (entire) array. It's related to the ArraySegment behavior rather than that of SelectMany.

Comment: @Matt - ahh ok, makes sense, learn something new every day :) cheers.

Answer (score 8):

This can be a potentially tricky issue because `ArraySegment` is really only a view wrapper around an original array, and there is no limit to the number of `ArraySegment`s created around an Array (which is stored as a reference, not a copy, in the `ArraySegment.Array` property) - so you can't do any tricks by just extracting the arrays in one go.

That being said, your initial code can be improved slightly wrt. buffering the copies. This assumes that you want values in segments that point at the same values in the underlying array to be duplicated in the result array.

```
public byte[] ConvertToByteArray(IList<ArraySegment<byte>> list)
{
    var bytes = new byte[list.Sum (asb => asb.Count)];
    int pos = 0;

    foreach (var asb in list) {
        Buffer.BlockCopy (asb.Array, asb.Offset, bytes, pos, asb.Count);
        pos += asb.Count;
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

That does iterate over `list` twice (to get the total count, but for larger ArraySegments, the buffered copying is a bigger win than the extra iteration is a loss, in my synthetic test). As always, measure if its a performance-critical code path.

Comment: I see your point about block copy and about ArraySegment. The use case is converting the dynamic buffer from Receive on Socket to move it into a Stream. There may be a more appropriate way of doing that, I am experimenting before I ask the question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think there is an error. You are incrementing pos before doing the Buffer.BlockCopy (pos += asb.Count will pass as the parameter to Bufer.BlockCopy the summed value, so in the first cycle, pos is list[0].count instead of being 0. Move pos += asb.Count to the next line and add some brackets.

Comment: @xanatos You are of course correct. Trying to get cute in the short-form SO answer and not re-testing.

Comment: @jasonsirota: If you're going to be writing it to a stream anyway, do you really need a single buffer first? Can't you just call Stream.Write several times, once for each ArraySegment?

Comment: +1 @Matt because I didn't know you could do the pos += asb.Count as a parameter, and I didn't know the precedence of it (if it was like ++pos or like pos++), so I had to check it.

Comment: @johnskeet yes, that is what I will end up doing, thank you. I just wanted to know if there was a way to convert without iterating. Short answer: no.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this very nice explanation of your problem when struggling with the same issue once. (http://www.fotia.co.uk/fotia/DN.01.CoVariantGenericList.aspx)

I have since achieved the type of code you may wish to use, by creating a class that inherits from the generic list class and adding a constructor that does the iteration for me.

```
public class bytes : List<byte>
{
    public bytes()
    {
    }

    public bytes (IList<ArraySegment<byte>> list)
    {
       for ( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )  
       {
           this.Add(asb.Array[i]);
       }        
    }
}
```

Then, in your code you can just have:

```
bytes myList = new bytes(yourIList);
```

This doesn't remove the need to to the conversion but it does hide the code.

Comment: What is the `asb` you have there? Should that be your `list` constructor argument?

Comment: I think it would be much cleaner to write one method to convert this rather than introducing a new class. This looks like an abuse of inheritance to me.

Comment: More than happy to be corrected by Jon Skeet. I'm curious, would this still be considered an "abuse of inheritance" if the class also provides other methods? Say the type of List was a custom component of some sort and some other calculations were performed.